# Combined microservice for user and organisations

Tags: design-patterns, microservices

I am building a new microservice based application and decomposing it down by business capability. Where I am little unsure is around managing users and organisations. Basically, organisations should be created first and then users can be assigned to them. Should I have a single microservice that combines both users and organisations or separate them out?

Answer (score 0):

have you referred to any microservices decomposition related documentation like this https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/06/decomposing-system-microservices/ ? As mentioned here (and many other resources on this topic), the decomposition depends upon a multiple factors.
eg. overall scope of your application, the deployment model, are your organization and user management  functionalities vast enough to be broken down into individual microservers, and many more. So the question needs more elaboration to get specific answer for your question. Or you may want to study microservices patterns if not already done.